# How to convert the results of a for loop into pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas, export-to-csv

Using the Haversine formula for distance calculation on a great circle, I use the following code to calculate the coordinates of any point between a known start location (with lat1/lon1) and a known destination (with lat2/lon2):

Here's the complete code:

```
from math import radians, sin, cos, acos, atan2, sqrt, pi

#enter the following numbers in the corresponding input fields:
#lat1 = starting latitude = 33.95 
#lon1 = starting longitude = -118.40
#lat2 = destination latitude = 40.6333 
#lon2= destination longitude = -73.7833
lat1 = radians(float(input("Starting latitude: ")))
lon1 = radians(float(input("Starting longitude: ")))
lat2 = radians(float(input("Destination latitude: ")))
lon2 = radians(float(input("Destination longitude: ")))

#Haversine formula to calculate the distance, in radians, between starting point and destination:
d = ((6371.01 * acos(sin(lat1)*sin(lat2) + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(lon1 - lon2)))/1.852)/(180*60/pi)  

import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0, 1, 0.2)
for f in x:
    A=sin((1-f)*d)/sin(d)
    B=sin(f*d)/sin(d)
    x = A*cos(lat1)*cos(lon1) +  B*cos(lat2)*cos(lon2)
    y = A*cos(lat1)*sin(lon1) +  B*cos(lat2)*sin(lon2)
    z = A*sin(lat1)           +  B*sin(lat2)
    lat_rad=atan2(z,sqrt(x**2+y**2))
    lon_rad=atan2(y,x)
    lat_deg = lat_rad*180/pi
    lon_deg = lon_rad*180/pi
    print('%.2f' %f, '%.4f' %lat_deg, '%.4f' %lon_deg)
```

I use the `np.arange()` function to do a fractional iteration, f, between 0 (the starting point) and 1 (the destination).

The output of the for loop is:

```
0.00 33.9500 -118.4000
0.20 36.6040 -110.2685
0.40 38.6695 -101.6259
0.60 40.0658 -92.5570
0.80 40.7311 -83.2103
```

Where, the first number is the fraction (f); the second number is the latitude (lat_deg) and the third number is the longitude (lon_deg).

My question is: how do I convert the output of my code into a pandas (3x6) data frame with the data arranged in 3 columns with header Fraction (col1), Latitude (col2), Longitude (col3)?

Once the output is in a pandas data frame I can then easily write the data into a CSV file.

Comment: what is d? it is not listed in your code

Comment: I added the calculation of d (=distance between starting point and destination) to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. With the following modifications, you will be able to get your CSV:

1. Append your values to a list instead of printing them.
2. [Convert the result to a dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

Below is your code with the required updates. I have now tested this and it works all the way to the final CSV.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from math import radians, sin, cos, acos, atan2, sqrt, pi

# Numbers per your instructions
lat1 = radians(float(33.95))
lon1 = radians(float(-118.40))
lat2 = radians(float(40.6333))
lon2 = radians(float(-73.7833))

#Haversine formula to calculate the distance, in radians, between starting point and destination:
d = ((6371.01 * acos(sin(lat1)*sin(lat2) + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(lon1 - lon2)))/1.852)/(180*60/pi)  

x = np.arange(0, 1, 0.2)

# An empty list into which we'll append each list of values
res = []

for f in x:
    A=sin((1-f)*d)/sin(d)
    B=sin(f*d)/sin(d)
    x = A*cos(lat1)*cos(lon1) +  B*cos(lat2)*cos(lon2)
    y = A*cos(lat1)*sin(lon1) +  B*cos(lat2)*sin(lon2)
    z = A*sin(lat1)           +  B*sin(lat2)
    lat_rad=atan2(z,sqrt(x**2+y**2))
    lon_rad=atan2(y,x)
    lat_deg = lat_rad*180/pi
    lon_deg = lon_rad*180/pi
    # Add the desired values, creating a list of lists
    res.append([f, lat_deg, lon_deg])

# Convert the result to a dataframe
res_df= pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['Fraction', 'Latitude', 'Longitude'])

# Voila! You can now save to CSV
res_df.to_csv('coordinates.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: res_arr was not defined so I modified to ```res_arr=res.append([f, lat_deg, lon_deg])```. Now the code executed but it prints out an Empty DataFrame

Comment: `res.append` doesn't return anything. Try `res_arr = res`

Comment: I have updated my answer with your code modified to produce the pandas dataframe and the final CSV. Please accept this solution if if satisfies your requirements.

Comment: I’m glad I could help! Would you mind accepting my solution?